# Sending keypress to a form field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a user to click on something, have it auto-fill an input field (a search field), and then automatically send an enter keypress to execute it. My code below, it does not appear to send the enter command. It my code, I will have to manually press enter to start the search. Is there an error in the code? Thanks.

jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/eliluong/5n50mun2/

```
$('.clickme').bind('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var input_text = "search for this";
    $('#quicksearch').val(input_text);
    $('#quicksearch').focus();
    var e = jQuery.Event('keypress');
    e.which = 13;
    $('#quicksearch').trigger(e);
});
```

Comment: Use `submit()` method of the form instead.

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure but replace this:

```
$('#quicksearch').trigger(e);
```

With This:

```
$(this).trigger(e.which);
```

Alternatively, you could just use JQueries Built in submit function, no need to capture the keypress:

```
$('.clickme').click(function () {
    var input_text = "search for this";
    $('#quicksearch').val(input_text);
    $('#quicksearch').submit();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure why none of these are working. The search function executes if I manually press enter, however. The jquery I'm working with searches as you type, so I ended up just calling their search function after replacing text in the input field, which seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.which = 13; 
e.keyCode = 13;
$("#quicksearch").trigger(e);
```

Haven't you forgotten **the third line** of the above code?

Moreover you have to click the button that **submits the form**, not the #quicksearch button :)